# Change Default Settings For Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and in startup I choose `Web Developer` for default settings but I want `C# settings`.How I can change default settings to c#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Choose Tools -> Import and Export Settings...
> 2. Select Reset All Settings and click Next
> 3. Select whether you would like to save the current settings and click Next
> 4. Select the settings you want to use and click Finish

From - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/4b09ba47-18d2-49a0-8cb7-7020706e034a/ (was written for VS2005 will work with VS2010)

Answer (score 4):

You can reset it. Than you can select C# settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

> On the Tools menu, click Import and Export Settings.
>
> On the Welcome to the Import and Export Settings Wizard page, click
>   Reset all settings and then click Next.
>
> If you want to save your current settings combination, click Yes, save
>   my current settings, specify a file name, and then click Next.
>
> —or—
>
> If you want to delete your current settings combination, choose No,
>   just reset settings, overwriting my current settings, and then click
>   Next. This option does not delete default settings, which will still
>   be available the next time you use the wizard.
>
> In Which collection of settings do you want to reset to, select a
>   settings collection from the list.
>
> Click Finish.